# ARIMA with high frequency data of only one month

Tags: arima, seasonality

I'm analyzing some data I collected for 4 weeks I would like to correlate a dependent variable ($y$) to other 10 independent metereological variables ($x_1, \dots, x_{10}$). ARIMA was suggested as possible statistical method:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36789439/multivariate-analysis-on-time-series-data.

The problem is that my measurements are made every five minutes and I have only one month of measures. I was thinking that ARIMA could not work so well with this little temporal interval, is it right?

Comment: Do you have 288 measurements? That seems like a reasonable amount to me at first blush.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have independent data, you will want to either run an ARIMAX model or a regression with ARIMA errors. [There is a difference.](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/) Parameter estimates are easier to interpret in regressions with ARIMA errors, which R's `auto.arima()` and other functions fit.

If you have meteorological data, I'd expect intra-daily seasonality. With data in 5 minute buckets, this translates to a season length of 288, which is quite a lot. Fitting an ARIMA model to long-season data will take a while. In R, you can simulate four weeks' worth of white noise with a seasonal period of 288 and then check how long fitting an ARIMA model will take like this:

```
library(forecast)
set.seed(1)
foo <- ts(rnorm(4*7*24*12),frequency=24*12)
system.time(auto.arima(foo))
```

I'd love to tell you how long this took on my machine, but after five minutes, it's still running, and I'm getting bored. It might be better not to let `auto.arima()` choose the seasonality, but to [force seasonality by setting the parameter `D=1`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37046275/452096) - this might speed up matters a bit.

Other software may have similar possibilities of prespecifying the seasonality, and of including covariates.

Comment: Thank you Stephan, I tried to run your example code and my computer crashed, so I think this frequency is too high to run the code. I'll try to set the parameter D=1 and I'll write for new responses. I read the site you suggested me, http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/ , and I'll try also to run regression on the arima residuals (run without covariates).

Comment: You are welcome. If my post answered your question, please consider [accepting it by clicking the little checkmark under the voting buttons](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer). You get reputation, I get reputation, the next user to come along sees that the post answers the question - everyone wins.